# Stuck with hexo variables scope

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, hexo

I have been code a Hexo theme recently, now I stuck with the variables. I read the doc, but could not get much info.

For example:
On the last paragraph of the variables of the doc:

```
Tag (tag): Same as index layout but add the following variables.

Variable    Description
page.tag    Tag name
```

Is this means I could use 'page.tag' in tag layout? But what made a `tag` layout?

I have created a `tag.jade`, and a page named `tags` using `tag.jade`, and  I also add some test tags in other articles,

In my `tag.jade`, I have 

    `p= page.tag`

But there is nothing output.

Also, the doc says

> Same as index layout

But try to use `page.posts` ( I can use it in index.jade)  in `tag.jade`, but `undefined`,

So What does it mean `Tag (tag)` in the doc, is it the scope of the variables? what makes these scope?

Sorry for my writings, I am really comfused about these variables.

Comment: Attached the docs url: https://hexo.io/docs/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

You may have misunderstood the tag layout.

A tag layout is used for generate a tag cloud page, like my blog: http://blog.xcatliu.com/tags/

You don't need to write a page which layout is tag, instead, you can use https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-generator-tag to generate the tag page.